# Post Automatically Using Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, feed

I just created an app on Facebook (Open Graph). I want to publish a feed on the user's wall if they read that page. I can get it to execute in Unix Terminal but its not working via PHP or HTML. It should function like the Washington Post Social Reader where whenever you read a story, it shows up on your wall..saying "XYZ read a story on WashingtonPost"..I've got all setup done except for the last part.

I need to use a function in my website that will fire when the page loads..sending a post request to Facebook and publish the feed to the reading user (Provided they have authenticated my app).

I tried using the following method provided by Facebook but it didn't work

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function postCook()
{
    FB.api('/me/YOUR_NAMESPACE:cook' +
                '?recipe=http://example.com/cookie.html','post',
                function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
        } else {
            alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
    });
}
</script>
```

Please help ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log the error and see what Facebook tells you:

```
console.log('Error occured => ' + response.error.message);
```

Also use the [Facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check your meta tags.

Comment: I get the following message (Warnings) :
'
Inferred Property: The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The og:image property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The og:locale property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.'

But i have made the changes to the meta tags..even then the msg persists

Comment: Without url it's hard to tell : ] Can you post it? In most cases it's the og:url meta tag which causes the problems. Ah! One more thing: Check whether you have the open graph namespace declared in the head prefix like so: `<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# YOUR_NAMESPACE: 
    http://ogp.me/ns/apps/YOUR_NAMESPACE#">`